# Using mod_rewrite correctly on Debian server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, debian

the good old mod_rewrite. I can't seem to get it right.

Typical scenario: A user types in "http://domain.com/page"
I want that the user is being redirected to "http://domain.com/page/page2"

My htaccess file looks as follows:

```
RewriteEngine   on
RewriteBase     /var/www/

RewriteRule     ^/page/$    page/page2 
RewriteRule     ^/bla/$     page/page2/bla
```

The first rewrite rule works, the second on the other hand doesn't seem to have any effect. Any idea? Maybe a better way to do this?

And another question:
As I said the first rewrite works just fine, but the url is not pretty. "http://domain.com/page" changes to "http://domain.com/page/page2". Is there a way to keep the typed in url but still forward the user to the actual link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume the `.htaccess` is in your DocumentRoot.
How does your `/bla` containing look like? This should not rewrite the URL in the browser.

Use this:

```
RewriteEngine   on
RewriteBase     /

RewriteRule     ^(/?)page/?$    $1page/page2 [L]
RewriteRule     ^(/?)bla/?$     $1page/page2/bla [L]
```

Comment: The /bla folder has a index.php file, which should be loaded when /bla is loaded. Could you explain your code a little further? For example, what is the [L] parameter for?

Comment: @user1183106 Flag `[L]` stands for Last rewriterule. Meaning, do not processing any further rewrite rule if this matches. For more refer: [Rerwrite Flags](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.1/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l)

Comment: Oh ok. Thank you. I thought apache would do that automatically. Yes, the code works well, thanks! Only one thing that is still bugging me: the url changes into page/page2, instead of staying at page. Do you know, if it's possible to fix that issue with mod_rewrite as well?

Comment: @user1183106 The URLs should not change. The URL's change only when you have specified a `[R]` flag.

Comment: @user1183106 are there any other setting's that you have set?

Comment: Nope. That's definitely all. My htaccess only consists of those 4 lines. Everytime I type in domain.com/page it changes to domain.com/page/page2. I see you just edited your post. I updated mine as well, still same situation.

Comment: @user1183106 Do you have your site on a shared server? FYI tat update has nothing to do with the change in URl.

Comment: Well it's a virtual server running debian. I'm the only one with the ip tho, if you mean that.

Comment: @cherrun do you have access to the apache conf files?

Comment: Yes, I do (sorry, just changed my display name. The generic one was annoying).

Comment: @cherrun ok, post your `<directory>` `<virtualhost>` configuration for your `documentroot`. Ya the generic display name is annoying.

Comment: Ok, for some really stupid reason, I thought that clearing my httpd.conf file would do something good. Therefore it's empty now. I can't exactly remember what I typed in earlier. What should it look like? I just realize now, after deleting the httpd.conf file, that calling domain.com/bla resolves in 404. Dang. I should try and fix my conf file again.

Comment: Okay, again for some odd reasons domain.com/bla works again. Still the issue with changing urls is still happening.